# How to write where year in laravel one to many elequent relationship?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.5

I'm setting up one-to-many relation in my code. Now, how can I use `whereYear` case in my blade template?

I've tried this code but it shows `Method whereYear does not exist`.

```
public function awards() {
return $this->hasMany(Award::class);
}

public function user() { 
return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

$current_year = date("Y", strtotime(now()))
{{ $user->awards->whereYear('award_month', '=', $current_year)->sum('award_point') }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call awards as a method, not as a property of User object, as in:

```
{{ $user->awards()->whereYear('award_month', '=', $current_year)->sum('award_point') }}
```

This way the method `whereYear` is forwarded to Query Builder. Your code sample didn't work, since in it you were calling this method on a Collection object.